Can I use the langchain agents with the models provided in AWS Bedrock
Below is the code which involves the use the langchain agents with the Titan model provided by the AWS Bedrock.
But I am facing issue in this, normal RAG chain is working fine , but when I use the agents with the tools and Titan model as the LLM for them , then the code stops executing and it fails.
Things which I am using :

AWS Bedrock (Titan Express Model and Llama3 70 B instruct)
Langchain
Langchain Agents & Tools
4 Lambda Function (To execute the code)

Code :
rag_chain = (
            {"context": retriever , "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
            | PROMPT
            | llm
            | StrOutputParser()
        )
        ans = rag_chain.invoke(query)
        print( "Rag_Chain", ans) 

        agent = initialize_agent(tools=tools, llm = llm, agent="zero-shot-react-description", verbose=True)

        agentAns = agent.run(query)

        print("Agent Answer: ", agentAns)

In the above code rag_chain.invoke is working fine, but the agent this is failing with the below output as shown:
Cloudwatch Logs
In above cloudwatch logs the rag chain gives the output but agents doen't.
Surprisingly when I used the LLama 3 70 B instruct through GROQ then the agent are working fine.
Help me to get out of this weird problem.
I am expecting the solution for this problem , want to know whether there is the error with the code part or with the AWS bedrock Models

Specify the exact error message or behavior when the code fails. This will help in diagnosing the issue.

already provided in the hyperlink
